# access to azure invoices from API

Tags: api, azure, invoice

Is there any way (API) to access my azure invoce information from an application that is not running in azure?

I would like to get this information and add it to my ERP automatically every month.

Thank you
Bye

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Andrew, you can use the ratecard and the usage API. If you just want to access the invoice as PDF, you can use the new (since April 2017) invoice API. This API does currently not work for enterprise agreements (but it's planned)
The invoice API can be easily accessed via Powershell (just ensure that your AzureRM module is up to date):

```powershell
Login-AzureRmAccount
Get-AzureRmSubscription
Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionId 'YOURSUBSCRIPTIONID'
$invoice = Get-AzureRmBillingInvoice -Latest
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $invoice.DownloadUrl -OutFile 'c:\data\LatestInvoice.pdf'
```

More useful resources about this:

- [Microsoft Azure: Billing Reader role and preview of Invoice API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-billing-reader-role-and-preview-of-invoice-api/)
- [CodeHollow: Azure Invoice API – download all invoices](https://codehollow.com/2017/05/azure-invoice-api-download-invoices/)

Answer (score 0):

As of today, there's no API (Billing API) to do so for regular Azure subscriptions. I believe there's one if you have an Enterprise Agreement for Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Since June 25 2015 there are two billing API's available for Azure. Though in preview.

> **Azure Usage API** – A REST API that customers and partners can use to get their usage data for an Azure subscription. As part of this new Billing API we now correlate the usage/costs by the resource tags you can now set set on your Azure resources (for example: you could assign a tag “Department abc” or “Project X” to a VM or Database in order to better track spend on a resource and charge it back to an internal group within your company). To get more details, please read the MSDN page on the Usage API. Enterprise Agreement (EA) customers can also use this API to get a more granular view into their consumption data, and to complement what they get from the EA Billing CSV.
>
> **Azure RateCard API** – A REST API that customers and partners can use to get the list of the available resources they can use, along with metadata and price information about them. To get more details, please read the MSDN page on the RateCard API.

More useful resources on this:

[Code samples on Github](https://github.com/Azure/BillingCodeSamples)

[Gain insights into your Microsoft Azure resource consumption](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/billing-usage-rate-card-overview/)

[Scott Gu's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/new-azure-billing-apis-available)

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.